# Center options in hmenu

Tags: css, menu, center

How do I get the hmenu options to center on any monitor?  (Simple center in css doesn't work on our site).
I've tried to research options, but our coding seems a bit complicated.

www.sleepstudymo.com

Thanks in advance.

Don

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and then edit you post and add ad much info/code as you can.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `float: left;` from `.sleep-hmenu`and add `text-align: center;` on `.desktop .sleep-nav`:

```
.desktop .sleep-nav {
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 2px;
    padding-right: 2px;
    text-align: center;
}
.sleep-hmenu {
    float: left; /*remove this*/
}
```

Or you can use `display: flex;` with `flex-wrap: wrap;` on the `.desktop .sleep-nav` element and `margin: 0 auto` on `ul.sleep-hmenu`:

```
.desktop .sleep-nav {
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 2px;
    padding-right: 2px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
ul.sleep-hmenu {
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: bottom;
   padding-left: 5px;
   padding-right: 5px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```